# How do you set the image attributes using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL. I tried using :

```
img.info = {'Buyer':'Text','Copyright':'Text2'}
```

This is not working. Is there an  alternate way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyexiv2 library @ http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2

Comment: Is there some documentation related to writing of the tags?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for EXIF support which PIL is notoriously lacking.

Other people have made their own modules to support it: here is one that [claims to write](http://fetidcascade.com/pyexif.html) EXIF data properly which I found in a recent survey article of the topic of [EXIF and Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/28/getting-photo-metadata-exif-using-python/).

Comment: Most of that article talks about reading EXIF information. I was more interested in editing the EXIF information of the image. I found the pyexiv2 library located at http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/ to be the answer. I will update on how it works.Thanks